# Properly send https Cookie

Tags: go, cookies, https, httprequest

I'm building a small service that interacts with other server.
I must send a cookie with session token to that server. And use it later for my identification. But that cookie isn't set. And no cookies are sent back.
The request is made over https protocol.

Here's the code:

```
// ---> create Client
client := &http.Client{}

// ---> create Request
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", indexURL, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("NewRequest fail: %s\n", err)
}

// ---> define a cookie
cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "sess", Value: "value", HttpOnly: true, MaxAge: 0, Path: "/", Domain: "the.server.domain"}
req.AddCookie(&cookie)

// ---> fire in the hole!
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("client.Do fail: %s\n", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

// ---> read the cookies
fmt.Printf("cookies: %d\n", len(resp.Cookies())) // prints zero (((

// ---> not even launched ((
for _, cookie := range resp.Cookies() {
    fmt.Printf("GET cookie[%s] = %s\n", cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

I tried also

```
req.Header.Set(`Cookie`, `sess=value`)
```

but with no effect

Comment: Server sends back that session token.
When I check it in browser - I receive sent cookie correctly

Comment: There's insufficient information to determine why the server is not responding with a Set-Cookie header.  The code correctly sends a request Cookie header.  Perhaps the cookie name or value are invalid or the server is looking for something else in the request.  What is response.StatusCode? That might provide a clue about what's going on.

Comment: Settings other than Name and Value on a request Cookie are nonsensical.

Comment: Hannah89, response.StatusCode is correct - 200.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, it must be an issue with the server. Even without sending
a cookie, I can get a cookie back:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   r, e := http.Get("https://stackoverflow.com")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer r.Body.Close()
   c := r.Cookies()
   println(len(c) == 1)
}
```

Comment: Before bothering server admins I must be 100% sure that my code is correct.
I there any issues with sending a cookie over HTTPS?